# Issue with "ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to run bundle install on a github file for a tutorial about Rails testing. When I attempt to run

```
bundle install
```

It installs most of my gems and then gives me this very long error. I've attempted to update both xcode and homebrew and it hasn't helped. Any advice would be very appreciated!

Here is the error:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/Users/johnseabolt/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.7.6/ext/json/ext/generator
/Users/johnseabolt/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170209-69149-18f1540.rb extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/johnseabolt/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.7.6/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/johnseabolt/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.7.6/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
In file included from generator.c:1:
./../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:179:47: error: too few arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
                                          ^
/Users/johnseabolt/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/intern.h:797:9: note: macro 'rb_str_new' defined here
#define rb_str_new(str, len) __extension__ (    \
    ^
In file included from generator.c:1:
./../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:179:11: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'VALUE' (aka 'unsigned
long') with an expression of type 'VALUE (const char *, long)' (aka 'unsigned long (const char *, long)')
[-Wint-conversion]
VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
      ^        ~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in    /Users/johnseabolt/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.7.6 for
inspection.
Results logged to
/Users/johnseabolt/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.3.0-static/json-1.7.6/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing json (1.7.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.6'` succeeds before bundling.
Johns-MacBook-Pro:expense_tracker johnseabolt$
```

Here is the gem file for the app I cloned from Github:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

 # Bundle edge Rails instead:
 # gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'pg'

group :development, :test do
   gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.0"
end

group :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'capybara'
end


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Comment: Can you add the /Users/johnseabolt/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.3.0-static/json-1.7.6/gem_make.out
 so I can have a look at the logs

Answer (score 0):

Try to run following command and then run bundle install

```
gem system --update
```